# How can i use php conditions inside json data?

Tags: laravel, response

Below is the code inside my CategoryResource.php

```
        [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($this->children),
            'items' => ItemListResource::collection($this->items)
        ];
```

and by this i am getting response like:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Fast Food",
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Pizza",
            "categories": [],
            "items": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Ham \u0026 Crab Stick",
                "price": "20.00",
                "image": "up/products/c11/Mrn4OpjngYRCkRJ28rJ1LbXUOXy0XjTRyXU7eFoi.jpg"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i dont want `"categories" : []` when category does not exist for a category.
please suggest some ideas or ways i can deal with this issue.

Comment: does this not solve your issue? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

Comment: no, this doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `CategoryResource::collection($this->children)` returns an array, maybe empty or not.
If that's true, then:

```
$dataArray = [
  'id' => $this->id,
  'name' => $this->name,
  'items' => ItemListResource::collection($this->items)
];

$categories = CategoryResource::collection($this->children);
if (count(categories) > 0) $dataArray['categories'] = $categories;
```